# Access 365 Form Unbound text box entry repeats input in every record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am only a user, not programmer. In Microsoft Access 365, I created a form with some bound text fields from a table of records, that includes an ID for each record, and created an unbound text field to enter comments for each databased record-- which is the purpose of the form. However, when I enter comments for record 1, the text repeats for ALL records 2-infinity. How can I fix this? Note that the Table linked to the form is updated by another Access database regularly, and I do not want entries in this new field/text box to be wiped out on update. How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's not what an unbound control does.

If you want to store data, you need a bound control. Unbound controls don't store data, and certainly not data for a specific record.

If you want to add a comment field, you can either adjust the table you want to add the comments to, add a comment field, and use a bound control, or create a new *comments* table with a 1-to-1 relationship, join them with a query, adjust the form to use that query as its record source, and then use a bound control.

Unbound controls on continuous forms will always display the same data for each record. The only way around this is to use a bound control (well, or do complicated stuff on drawing the form, but that's an advanced subject).